# Replace blank values in multiple dataframe columns with NA: should I use ifelse, or else what?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

I have some string data that has blanks instead of NA's and I want to change blanks to NAs:

```
test <- data.frame(year=c("1990","1991","","1993"),
                   value=c(50,25,20,5),
                   type=c('puppies', '', 'hello', 'die'))

test
year value    type
1 1990    50 puppies
2 1991    25        
3         20   hello
4 1993     5     die
```

edit: sorry the data table wont format right here, but you get the idea from the code.

This is how I would do it in another language (iterate over all rows and cols):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(test)){
    if (test[i,j] == ''){
      test[i,j] = NA
    }
  }
}
```

But R hates loops and punishes you by taking forever. But if I try a ifelse() statement ie

```
ifelse(test == '', NA, test)
```

It goes completely wonkers:

```
ifelse(test == '', NA, test)
[[1]]
[1] 1990 1991      1993
Levels:  1990 1991 1993

[[2]]
[1] 50 25 20  5

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] 1990 1991      1993
Levels:  1990 1991 1993

[[5]]
[1] 50 25 20  5

[[6]]
[1] puppies         hello   die    
Levels:  die hello puppies

[[7]]
[1] 1990 1991      1993
Levels:  1990 1991 1993

[[8]]
[1] 50 25 20  5

[[9]]
[1] puppies         hello   die    
Levels:  die hello puppies

[[10]]
[1] NA

[[11]]
[1] 50 25 20  5

[[12]]
[1] puppies         hello   die    
Levels:  die hello puppies
```

What gives? Is there an easy way to apply it to the whole data frame like you would a vector?

For example:

```
ifelse(test$year == '', NA, test$year)
```

Appropriately gives:

> [1]  2  3 NA  4

Comment: You could use `test[test==''] <- NA;library(gdata);
test <- drop.levels(test); str(test)`

Comment: @akrun, I think you misunderstood my answer. Also, why `gdata::drop.levels` and not just `droplevels` from base R?

Comment: @Ananda Mahto.  Yes, I forgot about `droplevels`.  It can be used.  Also, I didn't have your "SOfun" installed.  So, didn't check the results.

Comment: `ifelse(test == '', NA, test)` doesn't work because you want to compare and replace individual columns at a time, not an entire row of `test`. One way to do that is `apply/sapply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this *without* a package, but I've implemented this in a function called `makemeNA` in [my GitHub-only "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

```
## Get the package
library(devtools)
install_github("SOfun", "mrdwab")

## Load the package and use the function
library(SOfun)
makemeNA(test, "")
#   year value    type
# 1 1990    50 puppies
# 2 1991    25    <NA>
# 3   NA    20   hello
# 4 1993     5     die
```

The function makes use of `type.convert` to change the column types as if you were reading in the data for the first time.

```
str(.Last.value)
# 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ year : int  1990 1991 NA 1993
#  $ value: int  50 25 20 5
#  $ type : Factor w/ 3 levels "die","hello",..: 3 NA 2 1
```

---

Essentially, the function boils down to the following:

```
lapply(test, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), na.strings = ""))
# $year
# [1] 1990 1991   NA 1993
# 
# $value
# [1] 50 25 20  5
# 
# $type
# [1] puppies <NA>    hello   die    
# Levels: die hello puppies
```

Thus, you would get the same result if you did:

```
test[] <- lapply(test, function(x) 
    type.convert(as.character(x), na.strings = ""))
```

(But the `makemeNA` function has a few more tricks up its sleeves.)

Answer (score 1):

Try following simple code from base R:

```
test[test==''] = NA
test
  year value    type
1 1990    50 puppies
2 1991    25    <NA>
3 <NA>    20   hello
4 1993     5     die
```

EDIT: check the str:

```
test<-data.frame(year=c("1990","1991","","1993"),value=c(50,25,20,5), type=c('puppies', '', 'hello', 'die'))
> 
> test
  year value    type
1 1990    50 puppies
2 1991    25        
3         20   hello
4 1993     5     die
> 
> str(test)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year : Factor w/ 4 levels "","1990","1991",..: 2 3 1 4
 $ value: num  50 25 20 5
 $ type : Factor w/ 4 levels "","die","hello",..: 4 1 3 2
> 
> test[test==''] = NA
> 
> test
  year value    type
1 1990    50 puppies
2 1991    25    <NA>
3 <NA>    20   hello
4 1993     5     die
> 
> str(test)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year : Factor w/ 4 levels "","1990","1991",..: 2 3 NA 4
 $ value: num  50 25 20 5
 $ type : Factor w/ 4 levels "","die","hello",..: 4 NA 3 2
>
```

Comment: This is the typical answer, but view the `str` on your result to see the difference between your answer and mine.

Comment: Although I chose the other answer as 'more complete' since it does keep types in order, this answer answers my more general question of 'how do I apply a conditional test to a whole dataframe.' I would upvote it if I could figure out how to get enough rep to do so.

Comment: The str output seems to be the same; see the edit in my answer.

Comment: @mso.  I think Ananda Mahto was referring to factor levels after you changed `''` to `NA`.  Check the difference here `test[test==''] <- NA;library(gdata); test <- drop.levels(test); str(test)`

Comment: @BrianJackson, Another difference between the two approaches is that using `type.convert` gives you access to `na.strings`. Note that this is *plural*. Thus, if you wanted `""`, `25`, and `"puppies"` to be recoded to `NA`, you can supply a vector like `c("", 25, "puppies")` as the relevant function argument.

Comment: @akrun, not just the factor levels, but also if you had columns that are otherwise coercible to a different format, `makemeNA` would do that. Example: `df <- data.frame(A = c(TRUE, FALSE, "cat"), B = c(1, 2, "cat"), C = c("A", "B", "cat")); str(makemeNA(df, "cat"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a solution if you just convert your data frame to matrix?

```
 test_1 <- as.matrix(test)
```

Then you could run your `ifelse` statement as you do it with a single column of data frame.

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse(test == '', NA, test)` doesn't work because you want to compare and replace individual columns at a time, not an entire row of `test`.

The right way to apply a function to each individual cell is `apply/sapply` :

```
> sapply(test, function(x) { ifelse(x=='', NA, x) })
     year   value type     
[1,] "1990" "50"  "puppies"
[2,] "1991" "25"  NA       
[3,] NA     "20"  "hello"  
[4,] "1993" "5"   "die"
```

Comment: Better to use `as.data.frame(lapply...` to preserve the type in this case